# how to use multiple input devices at the same time

Tags: windows

I want to use multiple monitors at the same time, that receive input from multiple input devices - all on one pc. I think that instead of having multiple computers perform different tasks (one playing a game, the other for editing code), and moving between them - I'd like my pc to receive input from multiple input devices at the same time. I don't want it to iterate (between different tasks - windows \ computers), since it's uncomfortable. I want multiple devices.

like two "mouses" or a mouse and a controller captured by different windows.

I think it would be very useful. is there a way to do this?

Comment: No this isnt possible.  Also, this is a dupe, but I cant find any of the many times this has been asked.

Comment: welp, nothing to do. gonna return to this later. make a personal project outta this. there's gotta be a way.

Comment: A virtual machine that captures USB mouse and keyboard is possible.

Comment: I don't know much about .Net and windows api. so, that's what I'm doing. I remember there's a data handle or something you need. I don't know how to manage external devices to read input directly from the mouse, or if I can display graphics on screen (which is not in window form).

Answer (score 1):

Linus tech tips has been advertising *Synergy* for quite a while now, which allows using single mouse for different computers, if that's of any use for you.

I think that the best solution for you though, would be to try and run each game in windowed fullscreen mode or a borderless window, whichever is available.

After you start the game and you're waiting for something - press the Windows button on keyboard to get cursor focus out of the game and move it to second monitor to do your thing. I do that for years now and it works great! If some games don't have that third display mode then settle for windowed, but that option is rarely missing.